# Are there any known issues with TypeScript 0.9.1, ReSharper 8.x and VS2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, intellisense, typescript

The question is fairly straightforward really. The symptom is that, with ReSharper enabled in VS2012 8.x, intellisense simply won't work. Each time I turn on "Auto list members" and "Parameter information", *something* switches it off, almost immediately.

The only *something* I can fathom is ReSharper. When I suspend it, this no longer happens.

**NOTE:** This blog post from JetBrains - http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/24931358-Does-ReSharper-support-TypeScript- does **not** fix the issue.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm using it with resharper 7.x and have no problems. maybe downgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can completely disable ReSharper 8's TypeScript support in Options -> Languages, or you can selectively disable ReSharper's TypeScript intellisense by language in Options -> IntelliSense -> General. Select "Limited ReSharper IntelliSense" and select all except TypeScript.

Comment: Neither worked for me. I tried all 4 of the permutations of these too settings, and still no Intellisense.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get citizenmatt's solution to work for me, but ReSharper 8.1 fixed the issue, so everyone who is still on 8.0 and is bothered by the lack of intellisense for TypeScript should download the update.

Comment: Updating to ReSharper 8.1 fixed the lack of TypeScript intellisense for me as well.  Thanks.